# Adding and removing classes on forms using jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms

I have two areas, one area is for enabled items, the other is for disabled items. The user can click on Add to send the content to the enabled area.

The problem is, when I change the class of the form to make it delete instead of add, nothing happens.

I've made a jsfiddle of the issue. You're suppose to be able to switch back and forth how many times you wish, not just once.

You can see in the source that the class names are actually changing but it seems that my jQuery function doesn't recognize the change.

Please see the jsfiddle-example below:

http://jsfiddle.net/crW9m/7/

Here's my HTML markup:

```
<div class="added">
<form class="add">
<h3>One item </h3>
 <input type="submit" value="Add" />
</form>
    </div>


 <div class="deleted">
    <form class="delete">
        <h3>Second item </h3>    
         <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
    </form>
    </div>

    <div id="destination">
        <p>Destination for added items</p>
    </div>
    <div id="destination2">
        <p>Destination for deleted items</p>
    </div>
```

and here's the jQuery code that goes with it:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".add").click(function(event){

    var $form = $(this),           
        $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea"),            
        serializedData = $form.serialize();


            $form.removeClass("add").addClass("delete");
        $inputs.val('Delete');
            $form.appendTo("#destination");


    // prevent default posting of form
    event.preventDefault();
    });

       $(".delete").click(function(event){        
        var $form = $(this),        
        $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea"),

        serializedData = $form.serialize();


            //var submit = $form.find(":submit").hide();
            $form.removeClass("delete").addClass("add");
            $inputs.val('Add');
            $form.appendTo("#destination2");


    // prevent default posting of form
    event.preventDefault();
    });     


  });
​
```

Comment: You'll get responses talking about delegation and probably discussion on the use of `on()`, `live()` and `delegate()`.  To avoid confusion, tell us what version of jQuery you're using :)

Comment: I'm using jQuery latest that is hosted (1.8.2). It just feels like the class change isn't really registered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created an updated version of your script.

http://jsfiddle.net/crW9m/9/

My only change was to use delegate (jQuery function [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)) instead of your click event. The click event is added to the actual elements matching the selector when the script is run (on page load usually). If other elements are added later they will not be affected by the event since the event was added to specific elements and not to the general selector. A delegate solves this by checking for matching elements on the actual event.

```
// $(".delete").click(function(event){ /*...*/ }); // Replace this with:
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function(event){ /*...*/ });

// $(".add").click(function(event){ /*...*/ }); // And replace this with:
$(document).on('click', '.add', function(event){ /*...*/ });
```

Comment: Thanks! So if you use "on" it checks for the id's and classes again?

Comment: Exactly. The document (in my code) will receive the event and then send the event on to any elements matching the selector (in this case the delete and add classes).

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that binding to click events is made at document load, and just changing element class won't affect this bindings. Use jQuery `live()` method, instead of bindings.

```
$(".add").live("click", function(event){
```

instead of

```
$(".add").click(function(event){
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/crW9m/8/

Comment: This works, but the live() method is deprecated and on() should be used instead.